# How to inject only one mock inside Service class with normal instantiation to other instances?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, powermockito, spring-boot-test

Assume i have implemented next service class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional
public class ItemService {

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private final ItemCreatorFactory itemCreatorFactory;
    private final CommonClient commonClient;
    private final HelperService helperService;
    private final PrivilegeUtil privilegeUtil;

    public void addItem() {
        //How to only mock this in tests and other defaults to normal Autowired injection
        if(!privilegeUtil.isAdmin("bla bla")) {
             Throw new InvalidOperationException("Only super admin can insert data.");
        }
        helperService.doSomeRealLogic();
        commonClient.callAnotherExternalAPI();
        itemRepository.save(myObject);
    }
    // other methods
}
```

And i need to test insert new item in database, but before that i am doing some extra logic and if its fine so i can insert safely in database.

**Now i need to use mockito so i mock only privilegeUtil class but i need all other instances inside ItemService class to be normally Autowired without mocking it.**

So i go for next test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ItemTests {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @InjectMocks//Only mocks privilegeUtil but other instances is all null :(
    private ItemService itemService;//So how i get autowired item service instance but only mock privilegeUtil instance inside it and all other instances go for normal instantiation ???

    @Mock
    private PrivilegeUtil privilegeUtil;

    @Test
    public void testAddNewItem() {
        String email = "super@mail.com";

        Mockito.when(privilegeUtil.isSuperAdmin(email)).thenReturn(true);
        
        //Here i need to test adding item normally
        //But only skip checking isSuperAdmin part inside addItem method
        itemService.addItem(itemRequest, email);
    }

}
```

**So how i get autowired item service instance but only mock privilegeUtil instance inside it and all other instances go for normal instantiation ???**

**Is that possible? and if not so what you can suggest?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. As you are mentioning you test some database related logic, I guess it makes sense to use `@DataJpaTest` to let Spring create a [sliced context](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/) for you with all JPA/database related components.

You can then already autowire your repository inside your test.

What's left is to manually create all other *normal* beans using e.g. `@TestConfiguration`. Those classes you want to mock, annotate them with `@MockBean` so that Spring places a mocked version into the sliced context.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ItemTests {

  @TestConfiguration
  static class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public ItemCreatorFactory itemCreatorFactory() {
      return new ItemCreatorFactory();
    }

   // .. manually create all other beans

  }

  @Autowired
  private ItemRepository itemRepository;

  @Autowired
  private ItemCreatorFactory itemCreatorFactory;

  @Autowired
  private CommonClient commonClient;

  @Autowired
  private HelperService helperService;

  @MockBean
  private PrivilegeUtil privilegeUtil;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
     this.itemService = new ItemService(itemRepository, itemCreatorFactory, commonClient, helperService, mockedPrivilegeUtil);
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddNewItem() {
      String email = "super@mail.com";
      
      Mockito.when(privilegeUtil.isSuperAdmin(email)).thenReturn(true);
    
      itemService.addItem(itemRequest, email);
  }

}
```

... and then you can finally manually instantiate your `ItemService` and pass all your instances to the constructor.